# EF Core - may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've set up what I thought was a pretty simple database.. However I am getting the following error.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_User_Suburb_SuburbId' on table 'User' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Here is my CATALOGCOntext:

```
using JobsLedger.CATALOG.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;

namespace JobsLedger.CATALOG
{
    public class CATALOGContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Suburb> Suburbs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CATALOGCounter> Counters { get; set; }


        public CATALOGContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }



        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                entity.Relational().TableName = entity.DisplayName();
            }

            // User
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.UserName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.UserFirstName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.UserLastName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.HashedPassword).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Salt).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOne<Suburb>(s => s.Suburb)
                .WithMany(u => u.Users)
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.SuburbId)
                .IsRequired(false);

            // Role
            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().Property(r => r.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                .HasOne<User>(u => u.User)
                .WithOne(r => r.Role)
                .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.RoleId);

            // TenantAccount
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.TenantNo).HasMaxLength(20);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.Company).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.ContactLastName).HasDefaultValue(false).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.Email).HasMaxLength(500).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.MobilePhone).HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.OfficePhone).HasMaxLength(20);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.CompanyEmail).HasMaxLength(500);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.Address1).HasMaxLength(500);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.Address2).HasMaxLength(500);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.ABN).HasMaxLength(14);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.Database).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.IsLocked).HasDefaultValue(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>()
                .HasOne<User>(s => s.User)
                .WithMany(ta => ta.Tenants)
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Suburb)
                .WithMany(ta => ta.Tenants)
                .HasForeignKey(ta => ta.SuburbId);

            // State
            modelBuilder.Entity<State>().Property(s => s.StateShortName).HasMaxLength(3).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<State>().Property(s => s.StateName).HasMaxLength(30).IsRequired();

            // Suburb
            modelBuilder.Entity<Suburb>().Property(s => s.SuburbName).HasMaxLength(3).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Suburb>().Property(s => s.PostCode).HasMaxLength(30).IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Suburb>()
                .HasOne<State>(s => s.State)
                .WithMany(su => su.Suburbs)
                .HasForeignKey(st => st.StateId);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my user:

```
...
        public int? SuburbId { get; set; }
        public Suburb Suburb { get; set; }

        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
```

Here is my Suburb which was also mentioned..

Wondering if someone might highlight why the migrations work but when I try and spin up a database it it errors with above error..

Simon

Comment: Several users have provided the syntactic solution but didn't explain the essence of the problem. In your model, a user has a suburb (that can belong to any number of users). The tenants have a suburb too (that can belong to any number of tenants). the problem arises from a User having several Tenants. Because then there's an indirect relationship from User to Tenant, then from Tenant to suburb, back to User. That's a loop. And EF is telling you that it wouldn't know where to start and where to end the required cascading SQL updates if you update/delete an entity at runtime, then save.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error already says what you need to do. Specify what it must do when there is an action. You should add the `.OnDelete()` method to each foreign key definition.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>()
                .HasOne<User>(s => s.User)
                .WithMany(ta => ta.Tenants)
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

For further information please read https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ondelete-method

Comment: I pin this answer to my list of answers

Answer (score 5):

Your `User` entity `ForeignFey` **Fluent API** configuration should be as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
     .HasOne<Suburb>(s => s.Suburb)
     .WithMany(u => u.Users)
     .HasForeignKey(u => u.SuburbId)
     .IsRequired(false);
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // <-- Here it is
```

Answer (score 3):

For others that finds this question, this is enough:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
     .HasOne(u => u.Suburb)
     .WithMany(s => s.Users)
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

If you don't have want a list property in `Suburb` with `Users` you can do it like this as well:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
     .HasOne(u => u.Suburb)
     .WithMany()
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```