# Update-Database throwing FK cascade error (EF Core / C# / ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having a problem where I am trying to set up a code-first database through EF Core, and running into a problem when attempting to replicate the relationship between an employee and a manager (also and employee). When trying to run `Update-Database` in the Package manager I get this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ManagerRelations_Employees_ManagerID' on table 'ManagerRelations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
>
> Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> CREATE TABLE [ManagerRelations] (
> [EmployeeID] int NOT NULL,
> [ManagerID] int NOT NULL,
> CONSTRAINT [PK_ManagerRelations] PRIMARY KEY ([ManagerID], [EmployeeID]),
> CONSTRAINT [FK_ManagerRelations_Employees_EmployeeID] FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeID]) REFERENCES [Employees] ([EmployeeID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
> CONSTRAINT [FK_ManagerRelations_Employees_ManagerID] FOREIGN KEY ([ManagerID]) REFERENCES [Employees] ([EmployeeID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
> );

Here are the relevant models and the `DbContext`:

`ManagerEmployeeRelation`:

```
public class ManagerEmployeeRelation
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ManagerID { get; set; }
    public Employee? Manager { get; set; }
    public Employee? Employee { get; set; }
}
```

For the '?'s I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268985/may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths-specify-on-delete-no-action-or-o) question which has been asked previously, and tried '?'s on both ID fields, and Employee Objects as shown above.

`Employee`:

```
public class Employee
{
    [HiddenInput]
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LName { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    
    [HiddenInput]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public int Salary { get; set; }
     
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime OnboardingDate { get; set; }

    public Department EmployeeDepartment { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsManager { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
}
```

`CompanyContext` (`DbContext`):

```
public class CompanyContext : DbContext
{
    public CompanyContext(DbContextOptions<CompanyContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ManagerEmployeeRelation>().HasKey(M => new { M.ManagerID, M.EmployeeID});
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccessLevel> AccessLevels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set;}
    public DbSet<ManagerEmployeeRelation> ManagerRelations { get; set; }
}
```

Here I believe I manually set the primary key correctly according to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842509/entity-framework-core-two-objects-as-primary-key) question's answer.

I guess I am stuck because I see questions about this being asked, but it does not seem like the solutions are working for me, OR I am not implementing the solutions correctly (Which is highly likely). Can someone please advise on what else I can try? Or if I even implemented the solution from the first question correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in this answer to related question: [EF Core - may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970650/ef-core-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

you have to configure OnDelete() for each foreign key.